# Why is setting queue in a MPMusicPlayerController only adding first track in collection?

Tags: iphone, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitemcollection

I have an Album object containing a MPMediaItemCollection of the album's tracks.

When I add this collecton to the queue with the following line of code, only the first track gets added.

```
[iPodMusicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:album.mediaItems];
```

Oddly enough when I add with the following line of code, everything works as expected.

```
[iPodMusicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:[MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:[album.mediaItems items]]];
```

Why would the second line work but not the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MPMediaItemCollection Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItemCollection_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) makes no mention of a `mediaItems` property. I'd guess the property you're accessing is similar to `representativeItem`, as that would explain why you'd only get the first track.

It looks like you answered your own question. You should use:

> `[MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:[album items]]`